# On windows forms, set tab focus to a button

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have created an Outlook add in which at some point displays a windows form with four buttons present on it. I am trying to default the focus to the first button, however the visual "selected" border will not appear around the button whenever I default this button as the focused one on start.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: A button has *four* kinds of borders.  The combination of whether the button is focused and whether it is the default UI button.  If the TabIndex property or the Select() method doesn't get you the border you like then high odds that you are looking for the form's AcceptButton property.

Comment: Related? [C# Winforms Checkbox not indicating focus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38504895/123723)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either of these options to set the focus on a control in `Load` event of the form:

- `this.ActiveControl = this.button1;`
- `this.button1.Select();`
- `this.Show(); this.button1.Focus();`.

You can use the `Control.Focus` method in the Load event of the form to set the focus on a control only after the `Visible` property of the form is set to `true`.

After selection the button, the border of the button will be drawn in a way that shows it's the active control, but the focus cues will not be drawn.

*As a quick and dirty fix*, you can send a <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to your form:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
SendKeys.SendWait("+{TAB}");
```

If you are interested to change the standard behavior of `Button` to see focus cues when you select button in code or using mouse, you can create your own button inheriting `Button` and override its `ShowFocusCues` to return `Focused` value. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38504895/3110834):

```
public class MyCustomButton : Button
{
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get { return this.Focused; }
    }
}
```